# Intuition for this definition of "almost orthogonal" in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, intuition

I'm looking into an intuitive understanding of a following lemma in functional analysis about "almost orthogonal elements":

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $\dim X=\infty$. $U\subseteq X$ is a finite dimensional subspace. For all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ there exist $x_\epsilon\in X$ with $\|x_\epsilon\|=1$, such that for all $u\in U $

$$\|x_\epsilon - u\|\geq(1-\epsilon)$$.

I have come across a similar post, where this is stated instead ([An "almost" orthogonal vector in Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437922/an-almost-orthogonal-vector-in-banach-space)):

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $\dim X=\infty$. $U\subseteq X$ is a finite dimensional subspace. For all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$, such that for all $u\in U,\lambda\in \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ $$\|y\|\leq(1+\epsilon)\|y+\lambda x\|$$.

So first, I don't understand at all, why these are in any sense "almost orthogonal". The only thing that would make sense to me to call something almost orthogonal, is if X was Hilbert and we can say that the innerproduct is "close" to 0...

Secondly, I'm not quite sure how these two propositions above are actually related, they look similar and I assume it's just some scaling differences, but I'd still be thankful if someone could point out the connection.

And lastly, I have tried a intuitive understanding of "visualizing" this in 3 dimensions and choosing a orthogonal vector. In that case I saw, that we could choose even $\epsilon=0$, but this did not help me understand the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: "Orthogonal" in the sense that lengths are not reduced when taking sums or differences. In three-space, e.g., $(0,0,1)$ is orthogonal to the $x$-$y$ plane and the sum of $(0,0,1)$ with any vector in the $x$-$y$ plane is no less than $1$.  Maybe this helps ...

Comment: Ah yes that already helps, thank you!